# Auto Back-Up MySQL Database on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, database-backups

I am currently running MySQL on Windows 10 and have been searching for an Auto Backup solution for my database. I have looked into using third party software but most of it requires a license or is not able to connect to my server for an unknown reason. I am also open to any script ideas but please keep in mind this is not a Unix / Linux based OS (Which most of my google searches give me solutions for). I have tried running a script in Windows Task Scheduler and it does not seem to work. No files were created when running

---

`--user=root --password=***** --result-file="C:\mySQLBackups\backup.%DATE:~0,3%.sql" --databases "phpbb_32" "support" "local_bans_one" "global_bans"`

---

Any and all suggestions would be fantastic. I certainly do not want to be running export commands myself every evening.

Comment: You can schedule a backup from within MySQL itself, using the administrator UI. No need for any scripts. Off topic.

Comment: I'm sorry I am ignorant of this interface. Where is it located? If you mean launching in Administrator mode: I don't see any more options.

Comment: There is an administrative workbench program for MySQL

Comment: I believe that is only available for the Enterprise version. Unfortunately, I do not have it. I appreciate the input though!

Comment: You believe wrong. Download page [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/),